# How to set the scroll bar to my popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, scrollbar

I have thr[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgD6w.png)ee images inside my popup window, and i need to set the scroll bar to be able to see all of them, but it´s not posible to scroll throw the popup window to see the images below. Hope someone can help, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtWLA.jpg)
Regards. Sorry, but I can not show the code for a personal reason, hope you understand,

CSS properties below

```
.popup {
    background-color:  #08303a;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    max-height: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow:scroll;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    transform:scale(0.7);

}
```

Comment: please add some sample code and not image links.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code - I believe this one will be a case of setting the following CSS property to your pop-up window:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

For future reference - it's useful to put the code you've worked with onto Stack Overflow so people can review your code and give you a definitive answer. Without it, people will just have to guess.

Hope that helps.

Comment: .popup {
    background-color:  #08303a;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    max-height: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow:scroll;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    transform:scale(0.7);

}  these are the css properties of my pop up window, and thank you for your comment!